# Can i use HAProxy to inject raw bytes to client based on the request?

Tags: postgresql, ssl, haproxy

I have a bit of an unusual question.

I have HAProxy listening on a given port in SSL mode.  I can initiate a successful connection to this HAProxy instance using `openssl s_client`.

However, the usual client that will be connecting to this HAProxy box requires it's own specific packet exchange before it will start the standard SSL negotiation.

In order for this specific client to start a SSL handshake, it attempts to verify with the server *first* that the server is OK with SSL.  To perform this check, this specific client sends the following bytes to the server:

`0x00 0x00 0x00 0x08 0x04 0xD2 0x16 0x2F`

and then the server is expected to respond with:

`0x53`

And *then* the client will do the typical SSL handshake w/ the server (in this case, HAProxy ).

**my question:**

HAProxy has a variety of functions for injecting things into the response sent to the client; HTTP headers, for example.

Is is possible to inject specific byte(s) to the client based on the client's initial response without involving a special backend?

The approach i was going to try would look something like this:

```
frontend my_frontend
    mode tcp
    bind :9999 ssl crt /etc/some/path.crt
    acl non_standard_client payload(0,8) -m bin 0000000804D2162F
    <snip>
    use special_backend if non_standard_client

backend regular_backend
    server regular 1.2.3.4:9999

backend special_backend
    server special 127.0.0.1:9999
```

and then have something like this running on the HAProxy box:

```
#!/bin/bash
# ASCII `S` is 0x53
while true; do echo -e "S" | nc -l localhost 9999; done
```

Is there a way to mimic that ^ in HAProxy w/o needing a second server just to send the magic byte?

Thanks for your time. It's appreciated!

**EDIT:** Before anybody asks: `HA-Proxy version 1.6.3 2015/12/25`

Comment: why you tag postgres?..

Comment: Note that *"HTTP headers, for example"* isn't really a parallel example, since added headers are not really precisely described as being "written to the client" -- that is what ultimately happens, of course, but it happens because of a chain of events that would have happened, anyway: a buffer was allocated to hold the initial bytes of the response from the back-end server, and these headers were merged into that buffer, then the buffer contents are written to the client... all of which happens long after TLS negotiation.

Comment: This *might* be possible with Lua.  You can sniff bytes with Lua and you can write bytes to a TCP client with Lua.  I used this, for example, to write a "fake" MySQL Server that sends just the right bytes to convince a real MySQL client that it has connected to a server that is in the process of a graceful shutdown (so that a proxy with no available MySQL back-ends can return a meaningful error code and message to the client).  I'm less certain whether, after doing something like this, it is possible to allow the connection to proceed through HAProxy or if it can only then be closed (as I do).

Comment: @Vao Tsun: because this is the dance that the postgres client does with the server before it will start the SSL negotiation.